# How do I publish a new version for an app from another developer to Apple App Store and Google Play?

Tags: android, ios, cordova

My customer asked me to publish a new version for an app for both iOS and Android which used to be maintained by their former partner. Now that I'm going to take over the responsibility for this app, I wonder which data I need in order to publish a new version. The app will be completely redone, which means that none of the existing code will be used.

**For Android**: I think I'll need the originally used keystore and key from the original partner, right? Anything else?
**For iOS**: I honestly have no clue what I need. Do I need to originally used provisioning profile? Would that even work?

Note: The account under which the app is published belongs to my customer, not to the partner.

Thanks for any advise!

Answer (score 0):

Your customer will need to give you access to their developer account, which you'll use to sign in on Xcode. Then the new project you create will need to have the same `bundle id` as the current live app. That should be all you'll need to do, as automatic signing will take care of the rest (including provisioning profiles)....assuming Xcode doesn't complain about the `bundle id`, in which case you might have to unlist and delete the current live app. Doubt you'll have any issues though

Comment: Wouldn't they just be able to include my Apple-ID into their developer account? Or is this what you meant?

Comment: Yes. They'll need to add you as a developer to the their developer account